# Question about Geometry of statistical model

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, inference, information-theory

I am reading "Methods of information geometry by Shun-ichi Amari"
and I got the following doubt
Let $X$ be a finite set and $P(X)=\{p:X\to\mathbb{R}/p(x)>0 \forall x\in X,\int p(x)dx=1\}$
which in turn is a subset of all all $\mathbb{R}$ valued function on $X$ denoted by $\mathbb{R}^X=\{A/A:X\to\mathbb{R}\}$

I have doubts about the following statements below
(1) $P$ is an open subset of the affine space $A_{1}=\{A/\sum_{x}A(x)=1\}\subset\mathbb{R}^X$.
(2) The tangent space $T_{p}P$ considered as an element of $A_{0}=\{A/\sum_{x}A(x)=0\}$

Can someone explain how these two statements are true,I am confused in this,Thanks.

You can check the book link :https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Methods_of_Information_Geometry/vc2FWSo7wLUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover 
Page 40

Comment: Also, it seems you are [cross posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4591289/question-about-geometry-of-statistical-model). Please check this before doing this: [Can questions be asked on more than one Stack Exchange site?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/can-questions-be-asked-on-more-than-one-stack-exchange-site).

Comment: @User1865345 I have mentioned the source now please check,Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I have deleted the other one,now please if you can help me in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Since the support $\mathsf X$ is finite, for $p\in P(\mathsf X)$,
$$p(\mathsf X)=\{p(x),\,x\in\mathsf X\}\subset (0,1)^\mathsf X$$
and $\int_{\mathsf X} p(x)\,\text dx=1$ translates into
$$\sum_{x\in\mathsf X}p(x)=1$$
Thus $P(\mathsf X)$ is a subset of
$$\mathcal A(\mathsf X)=\left\{A\in\mathbb R^{\mathsf X};\ \sum_{x\in\mathsf X}A(x)=1\right\}$$
The fact that $P(\mathsf X)$ is an open subset follows from the finiteness of $\mathsf X$: if $p\in P(\mathsf X)$, take $$\varepsilon=\min_{x\in\mathsf X}p(x)>0$$ Then all $q\in\mathcal A(\mathsf X)$ such that
$$\vert\vert q-p\vert\vert_0\equiv\max_{x\in\mathsf X}\vert p(x)-q(x)\vert<\epsilon/3$$
are elements of $P(\mathsf X)$. Therefore, there exists a neighbourhood of $p$ included in $P(\mathsf X)$.

Comment: How you got $max_{x\in X}|p(x)-q(x)|<\epsilon/3$??

Comment: This is a constraint: "all $q\in\mathcal A(\mathsf X)$ such that" means "all $q\in\mathcal A(\mathsf X)$ satisfying this constraint". It defines an $\epsilon/3$ neighbourhood of $p$.

Comment: Simpler: in the subset topology inherited by $A_1,$ the half-spaces $p(x)\gt 0$ are open and the finite intersection of open sets is open, *QED.*  Statement (2) is an abuse of terminology: the tangent spaces can be *identified* with those sets, but are not equal to them.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, Can you explain how the tangent spaces can be identified with those sets?

Comment: Definition.  See, for instance, Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds.*